# Use API to gather statistics on my followers

Tags: api, instagram, analytics

I am very new to this and would like to know how to start gathering statistics on my followers as I am currently growing my follower base. I am subscribed to several statistic tracking apps but none are really good.

I wish to track things such as:

- Follower count by Location
- Frequency distribution of followers and tags
- Follower growth rate  by Hour, Day, week, etc..
- Follower Loss

Is this at all possible using APIs? Can anyone tell me how to get started?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct API call to get follower growth by hour and week, you have to get all followers every hour and store it in database and analyze for growth or loss every hour compared to previous hour and save it on the server.

You cannot get location of followers from API, you can may be estimate the location by checking for location in bio or analyzing all user posts and finding most posted location (this is expensive on API side and will have to make a lot of API calls to get analyze)

Yes, all this is possible to do using API, but it is a lot of work on backend, so if some service does this, it will cost you money cause they cannot do it for free, my guess is that you have checked all free or cheap services and they cannot do all this analysis for cheap.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have checked apps and pay for a few but still fall short.  I just need to know where to invest my time so its not a waste. I am a data scientist - familiar in the collection, storing and analysis of data. I just need some pointers on the best way to start collecting my info and then creating the proper analytics to grow my follower base. Who knows... with the poor services out there, I may even decide to sell my services/analytical model in the future. It is very clear that what is out there is not being developed by people with heavy a heave analytics background

Comment: so then I need to create a website and register it so that I can access the API. but now what about sandbox mode, will it limit me in the INFO I can collect or is it even an issue if I just snapshot my data ever hour or day?

Comment: you cannot do much in sandbox mode, you will not get approved if you do the project for yourself, you have create a platform/service, all professional looking to get  approved. You export data and analytics from https://www.picodash.com/export-instagram-data, and do more of your own analysis on data.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a broad breakdown of follower count in Google Sheets. This doesn't require API access so you won't get all of the data you are looking for, such as GEO. But, if you would like to see your follower increase by the hour, do this -

1. Open up a new Google Sheet
2. Go to Tools > Script Editor
3. Name your script 'IGFollowers'
4. In the code box, copy and paste this code below, but make sure to write this **replace 'AccountName' with your username**

   `var sheetName = "IGFollowers";
   var instagramAccountName = "AccountName";`

   `function insertFollowerCount() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("IGFollowers");
     sheet.appendRow([Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "yyyy-MM-dd"), 
     Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "hh:mm"), 
     getInstagramFollowerCount(this.instagramAccountName)]);

    };`

   `function getInstagramFollowerCount(username) {
     var url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + username + "/?__a=1";
     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
     return JSON.parse(response).user.followed_by.count;
   }`
5. Go to Run > InsertFollowerCount

NOTE: You may need to do a bit of formatting with the main Google Sheet, but this will get you some very long columns showing an increase in followers by the hour.